# How long does Po train for before Tai Lung arrives?

Tags: kung-fu-panda

After watching Kung Fu Panda, the training scene felt all too unreal -- the timespan in which they presented the training seemed to only take place over the course of several days.

My initial thought was that there was no way Po could train for such a short amount of time before facing off against Tai Lung (and ultimately defeating him). Consider the Furious Five, who were shown to have trained with Master Shifu for a long time, starting well in their early childhoods.

How long does Po actually train for before Tai Lung arrvies?

Comment: Every Kung Fu Panda movie has a random not long enough training montage in it, I assumed it was an intentional device parodying more serious martial arts films

Comment: That's true for all the movies. Training scenes are used to show character's journey in personal growth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Po's kung-fu training took a single day. That is to say, it took a single day to turn his formidable natural abilities *and a lifetime of self-training* into something recognisable as kung-fu.

---

> **All day long, Shifu trained Po,** taking him through all sorts of exercises—
> deep breathing, push-ups, sit-ups, climbing, and more, all while holding a bowl of
> food just out of Po’s reach. Finally, Shifu set a bowl of dumplings on
> a boulder. “After you, panda,” Shifu said, gesturing toward the bowl.
> Po stopped short, suspicious. “Just like that?” he asked the teacher. “I don’t have to do any more sit-ups? Or take a ten-mile hike?”
>
> “I vowed to train you,” Shifu told him. “And you have been trained. You are free to eat.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Kung-fu Panda: The Junior Novel](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/3396323)</sup></sub>

The [movie script](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Kung-Fu-Panda.html) agrees. The kitchen scene takes place at [DAWN] and the subsequent scenes in the Mountain, Field and Clearing all take place [LATER]. There's no obvious gaps in the sequence and it's the same bowl of dumplings as before.

> INT. KITCHEN - DAWN
> As Shifu turns the corner he sees Po's shadow as he performs some amazing Kung Fu.
>
> EXT. MOUNTAINS - LATER
> Shifu is sitting beneath a tree. Winded and wheezing, Po slowly works his way up the hill.
>
> EXT. FIELD - LATER
> Shifu leads Po out into an open field.
>
> EXT. FIELD - LATER
> Po's training unfolds -- deep breathing exercises, balance tests, push ups, sit ups, climbing, etc. Through it all, he never gets to eat, although he does indeed learn kung fu.
>
> EXT. CLEARING - A MOMENT LATER:
> Shifu sets a bowl of dumplings on a boulder.